# Do I have to consider old browsers like IE6 in webpage designing?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, css

I'm currently working on designing web pages. I heard a lot with regards to making other options for ie6. I was wondering do I still have to consider those kinda old version of browsers? I mean majority of web users are using up to date browsers which supports current css stylings. why still give much consideration with the old ones? what you think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I worry about IE6 and below?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360833/should-i-worry-about-ie6-and-below)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870109/can-we-worry-less-about-ie-6-issues-since-there-seems-to-be-upgrade-push

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786/should-we-support-ie6-anymore

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704361/should-we-bother-about-ie-8

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090874/should-i-support-ie6

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520422/ethical-dilemma-should-i-still-cater-for-ie6-as-a-web-developer

Answer (score 2):

See the [IE6 Countdown.com site](http://www.ie6countdown.com/). The answer to your question depends though. If you are developing for a customer who forces their employees to use IE6, by all means you should design for it. However if you do, I feel bad for you!

**Update**

If you don't have to, I wouldn't, at least at first. However, create a google analytics account. It will show you the percentage of users who use IE, and what versions they are using. If you find that you have a lot of IE6 customers, you can go back and update your design with more IE6 compatibilities later.

Comment: i see...I think maybe creating a simple stylesheet to catch styling for old ie's. atleast the web page is still readable even w/o the new effects css3 provides. right?

Comment: The web page should be readable, but may or may not. There are other considerations besides CSS3 and HTML5. For example, IE6 does not display transparency on PNG files.

Comment: ie6 really is a burden. i hope people would just throw that to the garbage.

Comment: Funny coincidence, I just looked at my google analytics today to see how many of our users were using IE8. To my horror, saw that 35% of our IE users are using IE6 and IE7.

Comment: users really dont know the word UPDATE. tsk.tsk.

Comment: @Saber I disagree, some of them have to use these older browsers. For example I work at a large university, and users are not in control of their machines. They cannot update IE because they don't have permissions. And some of them need older versions of IE because they are compatible with our legacy apps (whereas those apps don't work in Chrome / Safari / Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

The majority of people are NOT using up to date browsers. About half are using IE which will always be years behind the other far more modern browsers, Firefox/Chrome/Safari/Opera. So we will probably have to adjust standard, working code to work in some version of IE for the rest of our lives unless that thing would mercifully die.

The best you can do is look at who your visitors are or who your client is. If a significant number still use IE6, then you'll have to adjust for it. Google for "responsive design" for some ideas on how to adapt. Sometimes you just have to let IE users not see functions and features available on modern browsers but IE users wouldn't notice anyway since they won't be using two browsers at the same time. If they do notice the difference, hopefully they'll switch from IE to any other browser and do themselves and us and the rest of the modern world a favor.

Comment: i see...I think maybe creating a simple stylesheet to catch styling for old ie's. atleast the web page is still readable even w/o the new effects css3 provides. right?

Comment: @Saber - Use "conditional comments" for some of that. Or even to load additional stylesheets for IE. You can also look into frameworks like boilerplate that can help fix IE though all that makes a larger download.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no discrete yes or no supporting IE6. To some degree even IE6 should be able to display your page.

In general you should hope to design with the following constraints:

- Cutting edge development, as now HTML5, will be precluded anyway.
- Pixel exact design should be pragmatically handled, aimed at newer browsers, not IE6.
- JavaScript / Cookies are more severe requirements.
- HTML design should be done without losing oneselves time and mind with CSS details.

The IE6 is cumbersome if you want a DIV-all design. One may compromise in many cases to leave something reasonable in IE6.